# How to politely inform my new employer that I no longer would like to continue working there through a formal mail response?

Tags: professionalism, resignation, ethics, quitting

I would like to quit a job I recently took up for another better offer that has come along. It has been just a week since I joined this firm, but I have no legal/contractual bonding with them.

I now look forward to politely informing them that I will be resigning through a formal email.

How can I let them know that I will be quitting without appearing mean / unethical?

Comment: Nver quit by mail unless you are a remote worker. That is unporfessional and you are being pretty unprofessional by quitting after a week. You need to do this person. If they get mad at you, well frankly you deserve it.

Answer (score 4):

Do not quit with an email. It will give a bad impression, and in fact in the long run it might be one if not the only thing that your boss remembers about you.
Don't forget it's a small world out there, and I don't think you would want your reputation to go lower just because you were too lazy to tell him face to face.

PS: a word of mouth stating you are working for him can very well be a legal contract, even if you didn't sign anything.

Comment: Excellent answer! NEVER quit by email and in your situation, simply be honest. Explain why the other offer is better but make sure it does not come across as a bargaining tool. Thank them for their time and the opportunity too.